# 'buildozer android debug' error in kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I executed the following command in the  root directory of main.py file
which has build.spec file
I've SDK and NDK installed on my Ubuntu 15.04
Python 3.5.1
Cython 0.22

```
#buildozer android debug        

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
            load_entry_point('buildozer==0.30', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
            Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 987, in run_command
            self.target.run_commands(args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
        func(args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
            self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 162, in prepare_for_build
            self.target.install_platform()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 474, in install_platform
            self._install_android_packages()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 396, in _install_android_packages
            self._android_update_sdk('tools,platform-tools')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 340, in _android_update_sdk
    index = child.expect([EOF, u'[y/n]: '])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 315, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 339, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 97, in expect_loop
    incoming = spawn.read_nonblocking(spawn.maxread, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 455, in read_nonblocking
    return super(spawn, self).read_nonblocking(size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 157, in read_nonblocking
    self._log(s, 'read')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 115, in _log
    self.logfile.write(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 377, in write
    self.stream.write(data)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide i your question your code part which trows that error,  so those who is able to help you will have from what to start and make attention on your question, also try to format it as match as possible so it will look good

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I tryed to rewrite the 377 line of /usr/local/lib/python3.5/codecs.py.
From:

```
self.stream.write(data)
```

To:

```
self.stream.write(str(data))
```

The output is ugly but it is working and if you don't want ugly output than you could try that:

```
self.stream.write("\r"+str(data))
```

It is less ugly but still ugly :D